# C++: Find max element in array using recursive and reference variable

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a problem with findMax function using recursive find max element in array (code C++):

```
void findMax (int& imax, int n, int* arr){
    imax=arr[0]?arr[0]:0;
    if(n > 0){
        imax = std::max(arr[n],findMax(imax, n-1, arr)); // error here: No matching function for call to max???
    }
}
```

can you explains why and solutions for me with this error?

Thanks,

Comment: Because `findMax` returns nothing.

Comment: findmax needs to return an int the larger value

Comment: @ songyuanyao: can you help me with solutions? I want to result of findMax will assign to imax varible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::max` will return the greater of the two values, but the return type for `findMax` is `void`.

```
void findMax (int& imax, int n, int* arr)
```

So it is looking for

```
std::max(int, void)
```

which obviously does not exist.

Comment: Thank u so much, now I see where are my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing your function to return an int, you could just do a findmax when the range is valid then only call std::max after with that returned value.

```
void findMax (int& imax, int n, int* arr){
    imax=arr[0]?arr[0]:0;
    if(n > 0){
        findMax(imax, n-1, arr);
    }
    imax = std::max(arr[n], imax);
}
```

@CoryKramer is correct though, the error is indeed not passing an int to max in your example. If you just wanted to fix that, you could use this alternate solution:

```
int findMax (int& imax, int n, int* arr){
    imax=arr[0]?arr[0]:0;
    if(n > 0){
        imax = std::max(arr[n],findMax(imax, n-1, arr));
    }
    return imax;
}
```

Comment: Thank U with your solutions, I see my problem :)